# Zend-framework1 application not found - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

latest I got an application written in zend framework 1. It's not my project, but I have to improve some features.
Now I don't have any .htaccess and index.php in root directory.
When I go to http://localhost/project I got the structure.
Below I enclose screen of the structure.

[image: structure of project]

In folder public I have such .htaccess:

```
SetEnv  APPLICATION_ENV development
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And this is my application/configs/application.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

;ustawienia dostępu
resources.frontController.plugins.acl = "Application_Model_Acl"

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"  
resources.db.params.host = "host"  
resources.db.params.username = "user"  
resources.db.params.password = "pass"  
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"   
resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8"  
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "ZendX"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "PHPExcel"

;sesje
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000

;Setup logger (file)
resources.log.file.writerName= Stream
resources.log.file.writerParams.stream= APPLICATION_PATH "/../log/main.log"
resources.log.file.filterName= Priority
resources.log.file.filterParams.priority = 7
resources.log.file.writerName= Stream

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

I have tried many .htaccess, too creating index.php in root including public/index.php and still not working (returning 404). I have also tried vhosts - the same result. I'm using ubuntu 14 LTS and apache.

What's the proper .htaccess, that should I use?

Comment: Your vhost is configured incorrectly. Your docroot should be pointing to the public folder

Comment: But now I have removed vhost, I don't need to use the vhost. Is there any solution to make it working without it only using htaccess?

Comment: If you aren't using a vhost, you'll need to change the docroot in the apache config file instead, typically `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, there's no httpd.conf file. But I have changed document root in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` to /var/www/html/project/public and now when I go to localhost, it displays the page correctly, thank you. But now I don't have css and js files.

Comment: When displaying your main page, look at the generated code from your browser (Ctrl + U in chrome) and try to locate where the css file are being requested. Then adjust your templates so they look at the correct path